# Do I need to pick up every single thing?

Tags: hitman-absolution

After I finished the first mission, a list of objects appeared, the ones I had taken (including those I've discarded) were highlighted, the rest were grayed out. Am I going to be somehow rewarded for picking up objects during a mission? It seems bizzare that replacing a filet knife with a knife would have any consequences, but the menu hints at just that.

Comment: Surely you don't want to get to the broom dungeon and be like "why didn't I pick up all those brooms" http://penny-arcade.smugmug.com/photos/i-PPTPkRk/0/L/i-PPTPkRk-XL.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting rewarded for picking up these items. After you complete a mission it will only say **25/25** for disguises/weapons/challenges/items found.

Disguises and guns are available in contracts mode after you pick them up.

Comment: Note that any guns you find are important though, as they will be unlocked in Contracts mode after finding them.

Comment: Not all weapons tho, disguises you unlock will also be available in contracts mode.

Comment: @Ben and A1rPun, why don't you put that in an answer? Also, do they become available for use in other people's levels or for you to use in creating your own levels?

Comment: You can use almost all guns/disguises people put in their contract except for the DLC ones.